# Padding causing rendering issue in <td> using IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a table with a special color coded span that designates the status for a row in the table.  The CSS seems to render just fine in Chrome and FF, but in IE the red span does not appear to be rendering `height:100%` correctly.  I noticed that it had to do with the padding added to the `td` and the `button`. Its as if IE calculated `height:100%` before it checks the padding of child elements.

Please see this reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/vkjbu3cd/1/

**Update**

So after some more looking. I found that the padding on the other elements inside the row (ie. button) are not being calculated by IE.  If I make the padding of the `<button>` 0 then both Chrome and IE calculate the `<td>` height as being 20px.  But if I put the padding back on the button, then Chrome now calculates the `<td>` height as 32px, where IE is still calculating 20px.... why does IE have to do this!!!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange.

A hack would be to add a ridiculously large height to `blob`:

```
.blob {
  height: 500%;
}
```

Since its `td` parent has `overflow:hidden`, this won't cause a problem.

**Update**

Given that `blob` may have content, you could iterate through all `blob` elements, and hard-code their heights like this:

```
var blob = document.querySelectorAll('.blob');
for(var i = 0 ; i < blob.length ; i++) {
  blob[i].style.height= blob[i].parentNode.offsetHeight+'px';
}
```

Comment: I actually thought of that as well.. however IRL I have some text inside the `.blob` which will not be vertically centered correctly if I do that. I will attempt to center it whilst using your hack though.

Comment: Regardless... does this seem like a bug w/IE that should be reported? I can't imagine what IE is doing is aligned with the HTML5 Spec

Comment: I agree that it's a bug, but I don't know that reporting would accomplish anything.

Comment: haha.. given MS background w/IE bugs I have to agree with you

Comment: I accepted because your answer really does fix the immediate problem. Unfortunately my code IRL is more complicated and will require some more work to get rendering correctly.